# Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]. What did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I have checked many answers in other pages and forums, but I still don't get it. What did I do wrong? Help me

*edited. I have added requiring routes and app.use. It looks like function isLOggedIn is not exporting but I don't know how to do that. I did like this in another app, it worked there.

**auth-routes.js**

```js
const express = require("express"),
  router      = express.Router(),
  passport    = require("passport")

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }

  res.redirect("/auth/login")
}

module.exports = router
```

**user-routes.js**

```js
const express  = require("express"),
  router = express.Router(),
  authRoutes = require("./auth-routes")   

router.get("/profile", authRoutes.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render("user/profile", {user: req.user})
})

module.exports = router
```

**requring routes**

```js
const titleRoutes = require("./routes/title-routes")
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth-routes")
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user-routes")
```

**app.use**

```js
app.use(titleRoutes)
app.use("/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("/user", userRoutes)
```

Answer (score 5):

In `auth-routes.js` you don't export `isLoggedIn`. So in `user-routes.js`, `authRoutes.isLoggedIn` is `undefined`.

You can change:

```js
module.exports = router
```

into:

```js
exports.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn
```

or using `module.exports` into:

```js
module.exports = { isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn }
```

A useful link to understand export in nodejs https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: Can you add more info ? How the app is definded, how the routes are used and the error log

Comment: /requring routes
const titleRoutes = require("./routes/title-routes")
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth-routes")
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user-routes")   

/app.use 
app.use(titleRoutes)
app.use("/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("/user", userRoutes)
/Error
c:\Booi\DevLog\WebDev\wariLeichal\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Comment: I have edited my question. Help me, please. I am stuck.

Comment: I can't help you if I don't see your full code (or at least the important parts) and the error stacktrace

Comment: It's ok now. I move the method to another folder and export from there. It works now. Thanks for trying.